# Is there a way to disable quick charge on Xiaomi mi5?

Tags: settings, charging, xiaomi

Often it happened that I do not need to charge quickly my device so I would like to know if is it possible to turn on/off this option from any settings on the device.
I use only original cable

Comment: Cursory search on Mi forums shows that there isn't any built in way of doing this. *May*  be possible if device is rooted and one flashes a kernel that supports this (haven't searched ) but it would be simpler to use a Non Quick charge adapter ( any of older 2A  ones).

Comment: You can try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bth.studio.quickcharge) and put it on trickle charger mode when you don't want quick charging. Let me know if it works and you want me to post as an answer